# laravel scout temporary disable toSearchableArray when doing updates

Tags: laravel, algolia, searchable, laravel-scout

is it possible to disable `toSearchableArray` when doing updates to a record or is there any way to only update specific fields in a record in my search index?

Eg:

```
public function toSearchableArray()
{
          $item = $this->toArray();
        $item['title'] = $this->title;
         ...
         ...
         ...
         $item['category'] = $this->category->category_name;
         $item['uploaded_at'] = Carbon::now('America/Montreal')->timestamp;
}
```

The only problem now is each time I update a record it also resets its uploaded_at timestamp and re-loads the relationship which is one more query I dont need since it already has it set when I created the item.

So is there any way I can temporary disable `toSearchableArray` ? I only need to update a few fields in in the row in my index so there is no need to rerun everything in toSearchableArray

Like bellow only update the title and then update the title in my algolia index without reseting `uploaded_at` or loading the `category` relation again

```
$order = App\Order::find(1);
$order->title = 'a new title'
$order->save();
```

Comment: There is no way to achieve that. Could you share the reason behind? I don't understand why not updating the model entirely.

Comment: @JulienBourdeau Lets say that I only want to update the title. If I now update my title ``toSearchableArray()`` will also cause my ``uploaded_at`` to be reset with a new timestamp which is wrong since I created the post eg 1 week ago.

Comment: @JulienBourdeau But I also have stuff like this $item['category'] = $this->category->category_name; this will will make a innerjoin query on my category table in order to fetch the name, and I am making 5 more of these queries in order to fetch a certain name based on a join query. Which would result in my app doing 6 more queries which I dont need since I have the from the first time I indexed. I would much rather just update the specific field and push that to Algolia

Comment: @JulienBourdeau Since I already have the Algolia php client I used this instead ``$index->partialUpdateObject()`` which fixed it. Anyway big thanks for the other questions you helped me out with!

Answer (score 0):

You can use,  `unsearchable` function available in laravel scout.

```
$modal->unsearchable();

//etc.....
//Finally save the modal

$modal->save()
```

This way when you save or update it's won't sync to algolia.
If You again want to sync the model to algolia you may call `searchable` method as shown below.

```
$modal->searchable();
```

Answer (score 0):

To fully disable, add in service provider:

```php
\App\Models\Content::disableSearchSyncing();
```

Temporary disable:

```php
\App\Models\Content::disableSearchSyncing();
\App\Models\Content::create(['data' => 'Foo bar']);
\App\Models\Content::enableSearchSyncing();
```